# Extract data from an iPhone with broken screen

Tags: iphone, keyboard, wifi, siri

I have an iPhone SE with a broken screen. I want to extract the data from it so I can keep my photos etc. Though, there's a little problem. Since I can't unlock the phone with the passcode, and if I could, I can't touch on the "Trust" button. I just can't access my phone again.

I've read about keyboards that were connected to the phone's USB port. I was wondering if there's another way to fix this, since I haven't a Lightning USB camera adapter, so I can't connect the keyboard to my iPhone.

Siri is unavailable because of some weird problem, the phone doesn't connect to my Wi-Fi. The "dr Fone" software doesn't work, probably because of the locked phone.

1- Brocken Screen (not accessible)

2- No USB for external Keyboard

3- Siri unavailable (broken WiFi)

4- dr Fone not working (broken screen)

5- no iCould back up

I'm afraid I'm not going to see my data again but I put everything on everything.

Does anyone have the redeeming idea?

Comment: sounds like lost cause unless you were connected to iCloud.

Comment: @Buscar웃 yeah I wish I was connected, but I'm not so I'm hoping for anyone who has another idea... Thanks anyway!

Comment: Your best bet is to use the Search function on this site and go thru several dozen similar questions and see if any of those answers work for you.  It looks like you've tried everything already (except for restoring from a backup to a different iPhone).

Comment: Take a look at a service like [iPad Rehab](https://www.facebook.com/mendonipadrehab)  Unfortunately, not backing up either locally or to iCloud pretty much mitigated all of the "free" options available.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't backupped my phone in a longgg time (if I've backupped it already) so that isn't an option...

Answer (score 2):

Your best option is to

- Repair/Replace the broken screen

https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iPhone+SE+Display+Assembly+Replacement/61305

now you can log in and all your data is still there, and you have a working phone.

Kit for the Job costs $50

Loosing Photos- Priceless

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right... Because no other people had better ideas I think I'm gonna fix it your way, thankss!! (If someone has another good idea, you're free to still answer the question:)

Answer (score 0):

If you have backed up the phone within reasonable time, you can restore from backup to a new phone.

Depending how broken the screen is (It may be not showing you things, but still responds to touch), you may be able to use someone else's phone to 'map' the locations of the number keys, and in effect do it blind.  This would allow you to make a fresh backup, then restore that to another phone.

If the phone is recent enough, it may be worth it to get it fixed.  If the phone is not recent enough, then talk to one of these hole in the wall fixit places, and get them to replace a screen, let you pay for it, then bring the phone back and have them take their screen back.  In effect you are renting the screen for long enough to recover your data.

take it to an apple store, and ask them to transfer the data to a new phone.

Comment: It's the other way around. I can't touch the screen anymore but I still can see time etc. I think I'm gonna fix the phone. Thanks!